# types of wordpress events

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and have been trying to create my own plugin.

I am trying to call back a function by using add_action hook.
I want to know where can i get list of all events that can be used to invoke the function
and also i want to know can i configure my own event?

If yes where shall i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Answer (score 0):

Here is where the actions are explained in the codex, with a simple example

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Actions